# Irreducible representation of $1$-transposition groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

I would like to know the theory of irreducible representation of $1$-transposition groups. Could anyone provide me a pointer from where I can proceed?

Comment: What is a 1-transposition group?

Comment: @NickyHekster, In [A monster tale: a review on Borcherds’ proof of monstrous moonshine conjecture][1], a $k$-transposition group is defined as follows.

"Recall that a $k$-transposition group $G$ is one generated by a
conjugacy class $K$ of involutions, where the product $gh$ of any two
elements of $K$ has order at most $k$."



  [1]: http://preprint.impa.br/FullText/ReyesFigueroa__Mon_Jun__7_14_37_57_BRST_2010/MonsterTale.pdf